# Execute a bash script that shutdown a VM from a web page

Tags: php, bash, debian, apache2

I have a web server on Debian 11 and Apache2

I have a web page that is supposed to execute php script that execute a bash script to stop a VM on proxmox

The button that should execute a php script :

```
      <div class="mc-button full">
        <div class="title"><a href="stop.php" class="a" style="text-decoration: none;background-color: none;">Arrêter le Serveur</a></div>
      </div>
```

The php script "stop.php" :

```
<?php
exec('/var/www/html/minecraft/stop.bash');
?>
```

The bash script "stop.bash" :

```
#!/bin/bash
qm stop 101
```

When I try "php /var/www/html/minecraft/stop.php" it stop the VM as intended.

The owner is www-data, I did : chown www-data:www-data /var/www

I even tried to give 777 permission to both scripts

Comment: Is the www-data user allowed the qm command ro the VM? You should see something in the web server error log.

Comment: I added www-data to the sudo group and in the /etc/sudoers file I added :

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/html/minecraft/stop.php
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/html/minecraft/stop.bash
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/qm


In Proxmox I gave the power management permissions to www-data

Comment: I think you only need sudo for the /var/www/html/minecraft/stop.bash then in the php you need to call sudo /var/www/html/minecraft/stop.bash

Comment: I worked, thank you very much.

Now i need to do the same to start the VM and to stop the server :)